# How to get mappable children of an element in Closurescript?

Tags: clojurescript

I want to call "map" over all the children of an element, but goog.dom/getChildren does not always return an object that can be sequenced. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would combine `goog.dom/getChildren` with `prim-seq`. `prim-seq` makes seqs out of JavaScript objects which can be indexed like arrays and have a `length` property. I would leave extending native types alone in this particular case.